# How do I read a request's POST data in a simple JavaScript server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a simple REST server as part of a javascript tutorial, but I don't know how to read POST data, and I don't even know how to get the length of the POST data. (I have no trouble processing a GET command.) Here's what I'm doing:

```
const http = require('http');
const URL = require('url').URL;

const book = {title:"Dune", author:"Frank Herbert"}

const app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("Headers:", req.headers);
    accept = req.headers.accept;
    console.log("Accept:", accept);
    // contentLength = req.headers.contentLength;
    // console.log("content length:", contentLength);
    data = req.read(61);
    console.log("req.read(61):", data);

    let path=req.url;
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        doGet(req, res, path);
    } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
        doPost(req, res, path);
    }
})

function doGet(req, res, path) {
    if (path === "/basic") {
        console.log("Basic path")
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"});
        res.write(JSON.stringify(book));
        res.end();
    } else {
        console.log("error path");
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"});
        // res.write(asHtml("Not Found"));
        res.write(JSON.stringify("{Not Found: " + path + "}"));
        res.end();
    }
}

// to test this method, I use this curl call:
// curl --data "{title:'Stranger In a Strange Land',author:'Robert Heinlein'}" localhost:4000/add
function doPost(req, res, path) {
    if (path === "/add") {
        res.writeHead(200);
        var data = '';
        req.on("data", function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        })
        console.log("req.on():", data);

        var postData = req.body;
        console.log("req.body:", postData);

        var readData = req.read();
        console.log("POST data by read:", readData);

        res.end();
    } else {
        res.writeHead(400);
        res.write('');
        res.end();
    }
}

app.listen(4000);
```

So I can get the value of the `accept` header with this expression: `req.headers.accept`
But if I say `req.headers.content-length` it will throw an error, and if I say `req.headers.'content-length'`, it won't even compile.

How can I read the value of the content-length, and how can I read the POST data?

**Addendum:**
I should have been more clear about my results. The value of `req.body` is undefined.

Here is the output of the code above: (I modified it a bit for clarity.)

```
Headers: {
  host: 'localhost:4000',
  'user-agent': 'curl/7.79.1',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-length': '61',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
Accept: */*
req.read(61): null     
req.on(): 
req.body: undefined    
POST data by read: null
```

As you can see, the content-length, at 61, is correct. But `req.body`, which is where I expected to find the data, is undefined.

Comment: It's in `req.body`.

Comment: I should have clarified. `req.body` returns `undefined`. I have modified the question to show my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, which comes from the `node server` link provided in Arky Asmal's answer. First, when I process the valid POST request, I removed the call to `res.end()`. This looks all wrong, because without this call, the server never returns a result. But I fixed the code to read the stream using `res.on()`. Here's what it my doPost() method looks like now.

```
function doPost(req, res, path) {
    if (path === "/add") {
        res.writeHead(200);
        var postValue = '';
        // Read the stream.
        req.on("data", function(chunk) {
            postValue += chunk; // chunk is a buffer, but this still works.
        })
        req.on("end", () => {
            console.log('PostData:', postValue);
            console.log('req.body:', req.body); // still empty
            res.end(); // Don't send the reply till we're done reading the stream.
        })
    } else {
        res.writeHead(400);
        res.write('');
        res.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The post data should be in `req.body` but try parsing the body first. Try using `body-parser` middleware on your app, and checking `req.body` again

Here's the documentation for this [middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#readme) and how to have your app automatically decode your request bodies for you, especially if you're using express, which is how you should be implementing a [node server](https://nodejs.dev/learn/get-http-request-body-data-using-nodejs). The second link also walks through how to set up a simple JavaScript server, without needing `body parser` or `express` if you don't want to use it, and it comes directly from node.js documentation. It does require more setup, which is why `express` is recommended, but its up to you. Let me know if this helps !

Comment: Unfortunately, the value of `req.body` is `undefined`. If it had held anything useful, I would have been happy with it.

Comment: I think you may have forgotten the req.on("end") portion. You have req.on("data") but not "end". Since receiving a request is asynchronous and occurs in a stream, you may have to add that portion, and on the req.on("end") you can parse your json data.

Comment: Actually, your 'node server' link explained it. I had never used javascript streams before so I didn't use the code correctly. I fixed it by changing the code that called `res.on()`. I posted the new code in a separate answer.